# Increase Caching "Javascript loaded from CDN" in GoogleAMP enabled page?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, amp-html

I don't have much experience with caching using `.htaccess`. I found some snippets and that worked for static resources (like imgs, js, css etc), but in my project I have to include a CDN that has a different expiration time.

How can I increase my CDN cache time without it affecting my PageSpeed at Google insights.

I have attached the image as well:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to import all the .js files dynamically into our website. 
To do on PHP use the file_get_contents() function.

The first thing to do is to locate the external script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"> 
</script>
```

The next step is to create a .php file. Let’s call it externaljs.php. Insert the following code in it:

```
<?php

$files = array(
'ga.js' => 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js',
'bsa.js' => 'https://s3.buysellads.com/ac/bsa.js',
'pro.js' => 'https://s3.buysellads.com/ac/pro.js'
);

if(isset($files[$_GET['file']])) {
if ($files[$_GET['file']] == 'ga.js'){
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + ((60 * 60) * 48))); 
// 2 days for GA
} else {
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60))); // 
Default set to 1 hour
}

echo file_get_contents($files[$_GET['file']]);
}

?>
```

Lines 3 to 7: An array containing the accepted files is created. This is super important since otherwise any file could be embedded into your site, leading to potential security problems.

Lines 9 to 14: Since we need to adjust the expiring time for every script, we need a conditional statement to do so.

Line 16: If the script passed out as a GET parameter is found in our array, we can now

safely display it.
You’ll need to adjust the code and enter the URLs of your external scripts. Once done, just upload it onto your server. If you’re using WordPress, it’s a good idea to put the file in your theme folder.

Then, simply replace the external .js call and replace it by a call to your externaljs.php file, as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externaljs.php?file=ga.js"></script>
```

And you’re done. You can now dynamically import external .js file on your server and therefore, set the right expire header for each script

Comment: That worked at GooglePageSpeed but, made my site blank :P

Comment: You probably have missed the AMP limitations.

Comment: Here is the source,  `view-source:http://www.mutafaf.com/` Its loading but throwing errors.

Comment: I think its the same even after adding full site path.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pulling in js for analytics and ads stuff. You should be using the `amp-analytics` and `amp-ad` tags and not trying to pull in the js.

Comment: Nopes. Fetching AMP itself to enable AMP.
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

Comment: Ahh... sorry... missed that. Got mixed up in the other answer. The caching directives for that object should be served by the cdn and aren't under your control.